# How to enable assertions in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

here is an excerpt from my code containing the assertion

```
assert(age<30,'age must be less than 30');
```

Now, How to enable this assertion?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `--enable-asserts` flag:

```dart
dart --enable-asserts file_name.dart
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

`assert`s are enabled in debug builds of Flutter apps.  They are not enabled in release builds.

If you need to check conditions in release builds, `assert`s are inappropriate: `assert`s are intended as sanity-checks to identify *logical* errors (i.e., mistakes in the code), *not* to catch *runtime* errors (e.g. unexpected input from the users).

Also see: [why the assert function was disabled in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61220115/)